# Craft 2 -> 3 Upgrade Error

Tags: craft3

Database Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'n2-cr_matrixcontent_column1_locale_fk'; check that column/key exists

This is the error I am receiving when attempting to update the database for the new version of craft. I've checked for that specific table and confirmed that it doesn't exist. How do I prevent it from trying to drop it or otherwise fix this problem?

Comment: Bump. Having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

For reference to anyone else that might have this problem. Some of the tables in my database did not have foreign keys in the specific Craft format. This occurred when table changes were done manually without knowing about this extra detail.
Shout out to Brad Bell with Craft support for catching and fixing the problem.